# Progress 4gl, How to check if a record(temp-table and database record) updated?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Please assist. Is there a Progress function to check if a record was updated?

For example:

```
define temp-table myTT no-undo
    field tID    as integer
    field tField as character

    index i_dx is primary unique
        tID.

define input parameter iAction as character.
define input-output parameter table for myTT.

find first myTT NO-ERROR.

if iAction = "create" then
do:
    if not available myTT then
    do:
        create myTT.
        assign myTT.tID = myKeyGenerator("myTT","tID").
    end.

    assign myTT.tField = "". //assume it had a value if not just created
    
end.
else if iAction = "update" then
do:
    if available myTT    and
       myTT.tField <> "" then
        assign myTT.tField = ""
               .
end.

if new myTT then
    message "New record" view-as alert-box.
else
do:
    //Progress function/attribute needed to check if updated
end.

find next myTT NO-ERROR. //assume a record is available

run myOtherProgram1(buffer myTT). //as a buffer

//Progress function/attribute needed to check if the current record was updated by the call

find next myTT NO-ERROR. //assume a record is available

run myOtherProgram2(input-output table myTT). //as an input-output

//Progress function/attribute needed to check if the current record was updated by the call
```

The website is asking me to add more detail but my question is just that simple, so this consider this line just that, "detail" and irrelevant. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `buffer-compare` [statement](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/BUFFER-COMPARE-statement.html) or [method](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920605598.html) to compare two buffers.

You can also look at `tracking-changes` when using a [dataset](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920093405.html).

Comment: In this instance I just have one temp table, and it is not part of a dataset